# Ajax Post request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello I have created a script for login using ajax method I tried but this is not working for me getting unsuccessful can you please let me know why i am unable to work with this

```
function login() {
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var pass     = document.getElementById('pass').value;

if(username == '' && pass == '') {
    alert('Fields could not be left empty');
} else {
    $.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        url      : "includes/register.php",
        data     : "command=login&username="+username+"&password="+pass,
        datatype : "json",
        success  :  function(data) {
            if (data.status == 200) {
                alert('Successfull');
                var return_data = data.responseText;
                document.getElementById('messagearea').innerHTML = return_data;
            } else {
                alert('Unsuccessful');
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

it should run alert successful but I am getting alert('Unsuccessful') it means that status is not equal 200 can anyone help me out with that

Here is my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['command']) && $_POST['command'] == 'login') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass     = $_POST['pass'];
    $password = md5($pass);

    $check  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($check);
    if($result != 1) {
        echo "<div class='message'>Response Successful</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='message'>Username/Password did not matched</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `register.php` code

Comment: problem is with php can you include it?what it returns

Comment: Updated kindly check the post

Comment: you should `json_encode` before you echo. if you want to return html you should change dataType to html not json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` in `datatype` should be capital,

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/register.php",
      data: "command=login&username=" + username + "&password=" + pass,
      dataType: "json",
```

As per the server code, your data should be look like this

```
data: "command=login&username=" + username + "&pass=" + pass,
```

change the code inside the success handler like this,

```
document.getElementById('messagearea').innerHTML = data;
```

Comment: check the network tab, and see what is returning from the server

Comment: i checked the console to find the errors but the console is clear and if i write datatype with t in lower case the alert is working then

Comment: @MarkAlan change the data like this data: "command=login&username=" + username + "&pass=" + pass,

Comment: great it worked but got this result why is that so <div id="messagearea">undefined</div>

Comment: try to console.log(data) inside success and see what is returning

Comment: this is in the log i got <div class='message'>Successfull</div>

Comment: it means this is not working var return_data = data.responseText; ?

Comment: change the code like this document.getElementById('messagearea').innerHTML = data;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check xhr request status you should use 3 parameter in `success function`.

```
success  :  function(data,text,xhr) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                alert('Successfull');
                var return_data = data;
                document.getElementById('messagearea').innerHTML = return_data;
            } else {
                alert('Unsuccessful');
            }
        }
```

for dataType:"json"

```
if(isset($_POST['command']) && $_POST['command'] == 'login') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass     = $_POST['pass'];
    $password = md5($pass);

    $check  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($check);
    if($result != 1) {
        echo json_encode("<div class='message'>Response Successful</div>");
    } else {
        echo json_encode("<div class='message'>Username/Password did not matched</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: xhr and text are vars should i have to create them or already been defined? let me check this

Comment: already been defined ! You should check by console.log what they come out

Comment: Here is what response I got

Comment: alert ('successful')
<div id="messagearea">undefined</div>

Comment: Thumbs up for you mate

Comment: it means instead of responsetext i have to just mention the data as it will getting all the response ? and when i change datatype : "json", to dataType : "json", it did not work for me ?

Comment: yes if you change dataType : json ,you need to also change the return data into json format.I see you r return by `echo` in `register.php` that is not json So add `json_encode()` to change json format .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/register.php",
    data: {command: "login", username: username, password: pwd},
    dataType: "json",
```

Don't use "pass" into scripts jQuery, because sometimes it doesn't work properly.

Bye! :D

Comment: dataType: "json", when i write like this alert works  datatype: "json", why is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two more object in your ajax success function which will help you get more information of the request.

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "register.php",
    data     : "command=login&username="+username+"&password="+pass,
    datatype : "json",
    success  :  function(data,xhr,req) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            alert('Successfull');
            var return_data = data.responseText;
            document.getElementById('messagearea').innerHTML = return_data;
        } else {
            alert('Unsuccessful');
        }
    }
});
```

Also you need encode your return data into JSON so that your request return type match to JSON. If you closely look at your ajax request through Developer tool baar you will see that there are two more object return with your request containing different things.

1. Contains Data
2. Contains Request is success or failed.
3. Contains different objects in array